# How to delete duplicated elements in columns of csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I need help with deleting duplicated elements `language` columns that appears more than one time using python.

Here is my csv:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name2','name3','name4'],
                  'Year': ['1905', '1905','1906','1907'],
                  'Id': ['tt0283985', 'tt0283986','tt0284043','tt3402904'],
                  'language':['Mandarin,Mandarin','Mandarin,Cantonese,Mandarin','Mandarin,Cantonese','Cantonese,Cantonese']})
```

Where `f` now looks like:

```
   Movie  Year         Id   language
0  name1  1905  tt0283985  Mandarin,Mandarin
1  name2  1905  tt0283986  Mandarin,Cantonese,Mandarin
2  name3  1906  tt0284043  Mandarin,Cantonese
3  name4  1907  tt3402904  Cantonese,Cantonese
```

And the result should be like this:

```
   Movie  Year         Id             language
0  name1  1905  tt0283985            Mandarin
1  name2  1905  tt0283986            Mandarin,Cantonese
2  name3  1906  tt0284043            Mandarin,Cantonese
3  name4  1907  tt3402904            Cantonese
```

I am having trouble with writing a function to delete complicated values in language columns.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f['language'].str.split(',').map(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
```

Output:

```
0              Mandarin
1    Mandarin,Cantonese
2    Mandarin,Cantonese
3             Cantonese
```